# control brightness on pc

Tags: 14.04, brightness

I want to control brightness on pc. There isn't any setting for brightness.
I can control brightness on monitor but I want to change it more. Screen is too bright.

I also want something that change brightness by hour.

I'm using ubuntu14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at redshift?

```
sudo apt-get install redshift
```

This is my config file ~/.config/redshift.conf:

```
[redshift]
;temp-day=5700
;temp-night=4600
brightness-day=1.0
brightness-night=0.75
gamma=0.8
adjustment-method=vidmode
location-provider=manual

[manual]
lat=63.81415
lon=20.41742
```

You would obviously need to change lat/long. Perhaps is brightness-day the setting you're looking for.

If you want redshift to autostart at login, select Applications/System tools/Preferences/Startup applications/Add. Name: redshift. Command: /usr/bin/redshift.